# Dynamically sized charts in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm stuck on an issue where I want my bar chart to grow vertically based on the number of groups display in my graph.

I have a shared dataset looking at a SharePoint list then I have a dataset 
in my report referencing this but applying some filters based on date ranges.  I've then set that as the dataset for my graph which works neatly but there's a widely varying number of potential grouping categories to be displayed.  I was looking at this article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/27/charts-with-dynamic-height-or-width-based-on-categoriesdata/) which is a neat way to do it, but I don't want a manually set parameter, I just want it to grow based on whatever shows up. One thought I had was in the DynamicHeight expression was to check the number of "CategoryGroups" that show up but I can't see a way of getting to the chart object in the VB expression editor.

I saw an example of doing group by in SQL in the dataset editor but I don't get that option looking at a SharePoint list.  Is there a way in DynamicHeight expression editor to reference report objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the article, you can use a distinct count of the group items in a expression in order to dynamically size your chart.

The expression could look like:

```
=  (2 + CountDistinct(Fields!item.Value, "DataSet1")) & ” cm”
```

Which is (minimum size + size for each group item) in cm (or any unit you prefer)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no Fields available in the expression editor though. So the structure is:
1) Share DataSet points to a SharePoint List.  
2) Report DataSet is a reference to the Shared one and specifies filters.  
3) My bar chart has DataSetName set to the one in point 2.  
4) When I open the expression editor of the Dynamic Height property the Fields item under Category -> <All> states "Report item not linked to a dataset".  Even though the chart DOES have a dataset specified and the when I run the report I get counts from the SharePoint list.

Comment: Actually I see that it's disconnected so intellisense won't worked but what you showed still does work in my case